# Custom UICollectionView cell sizes according to label size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view but it's not very effective when it comes to longer string sizes because the font decreases in order to fit the label inside the cell. Does anyone know how I can approach resizing cells according to a string length? It would be appropriate if all labels had the same font size and just the width of the cells increased/decreased.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should label be multiline?

Comment: No, my goal is just to have the cell width increase/decrease

Comment: Did you set the `estimatedItemSize` of the flow layout and use autolayout constraints on all four sides of the label?

Comment: Have you considered determining the size of the text in the label using `someString.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]?) ` in your collection view's `sizeForItemAt` function and then adding any padding or what have you before returning the final cell size?